# If a blank POI marker is set on fire, does it still count as a victim?

Tags: flash-point

We've tried to understand the manual, but maybe the fact that it is written in English, which is not our mother language, could be making it hard for us to understand.

When an explosion occurs, and a POI is in the way, the manual said that you flip the POI marker and take it off the board, to the dead toll.

So if the POI marker is blank, does it still count as a victim at the end of the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, blank markers are "False Alarms", not "Victims".  They do not count towards the loss condition of "4+ Victims Lost", just like you place revealed False Alarms on the Rescued space but they do not count towards the victory condition of "7 Victims Rescued".